# Display a custom data if the value contains information in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to show a "YES" if the value contains information:

Here I have re that makes a relationship with id_order:

```
LEFT JOIN ps_surchage_eq_orders re ON a.`id_order`=re.`id_order`
```

If the current "id_order" have any data with this relationship, it's possible to show the value "YES"?

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT a.`id_order`, a.`invoice_number` AS num_factura,a.`delivery_number` AS num_albaran,a.`reference`, CONCAT(c.`firstname`, ' ', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`, c.email, addr.dni, gr.name AS group_name, a.total_discounts_tax_excl,a.total_paid_real, re.`id_order` AS RE, a.`payment`, a.`date_add` AS `date_add` , a.id_currency, a.id_order AS id_pdf, osl.`name` AS `osname`, IF((SELECT so.id_order 

FROM `ps_orders` so 

WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer AND so.id_order < a.id_order LIMIT 1) > 0, 0, 1) as new, country_lang.name as cname, IF(a.valid, 1, 0) badge_success 

FROM `ps_orders` a 

LEFT JOIN `ps_customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`) 

LEFT JOIN `ps_address` address ON address.id_address = a.id_address_delivery 

LEFT JOIN `ps_country` country ON address.id_country = country.id_country 

LEFT JOIN `ps_country_lang` country_lang ON (country.`id_country` = country_lang.`id_country` AND country_lang.`id_lang` = 1) 

LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`) 

LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = 1) 

LEFT JOIN `ps_address` addr ON (c.id_customer=addr.id_customer) 

LEFT JOIN ps_group_lang gr ON c.id_default_group=gr.id_group AND gr.id_lang=a.id_lang  

LEFT JOIN ps_surchage_eq_orders re ON a.`id_order`=re.`id_order` 

WHERE 1 

ORDER BY a.`id_order` DESC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add some sample data and expected result

Comment: idorder name order re (Example of rows), in the row RE show "YES" if there are an id order in "ps_surchage_eq_orders" table, the last table is orders

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `re.id_order AS RE` with `IF(re.id_order IS NULL, 'YES', 'NO' ) AS RE`

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT a.`id_order`, a.`invoice_number` AS num_factura,a.`delivery_number` AS num_albaran,a.`reference`, CONCAT(c.`firstname`, ' ', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`, c.email, addr.dni, gr.name AS group_name, a.total_discounts_tax_excl,a.total_paid_real, IF(re.`id_order` IS NULL, 'YES', 'NO' ), a.`payment`, a.`date_add` AS `date_add` , a.id_currency, a.id_order AS id_pdf, osl.`name` AS `osname`, IF((SELECT so.id_order 

FROM `ps_orders` so 

WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer AND so.id_order < a.id_order LIMIT 1) > 0, 0, 1) as new, country_lang.name as cname, IF(a.valid, 1, 0) badge_success 

FROM `ps_orders` a 

LEFT JOIN `ps_customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`) 

LEFT JOIN `ps_address` address ON address.id_address = a.id_address_delivery 

LEFT JOIN `ps_country` country ON address.id_country = country.id_country 

LEFT JOIN `ps_country_lang` country_lang ON (country.`id_country` = country_lang.`id_country` AND country_lang.`id_lang` = 1) 

LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`) 

LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = 1) 

LEFT JOIN `ps_address` addr ON (c.id_customer=addr.id_customer) 

LEFT JOIN ps_group_lang gr ON c.id_default_group=gr.id_group AND gr.id_lang=a.id_lang  

LEFT JOIN ps_surchage_eq_orders re ON a.`id_order`=re.`id_order` 

WHERE 1 

ORDER BY a.`id_order` DESC
```

If ps_surchage_eq_orders doesn't have that id_order it will be null, and the if will return the YES, if it has it won't be null and will return NO

Comment: THANKS!!!! but I have changed the order of "yes" and "no" because was showing "yes" when the value was null

Comment: Glad to help. I understood wrong if you wanted to show yes when was null or not.